# Probleam with MD5 used on builder 6 and MD5 java

Tags: java, md5, c++builder-6

I am trying to create a small function to login to a system that was written in C++Builder 6. When I calculate hashes in Java, they are not equal, the string in the database has a different encoding that I don't know.

For example, I generate hashes for "9511" and the results:

- Builder 6: `0;^»<-6KÒ.ìÑÁÿ4¼`
- Java: `58d2f92539a5492fe6ef1e7375c6e9b6`
  Java hash ok, on pass I use MD5 just on Java, but I've never seen that encoding.

Comment: Seems you are comparing the raw bytes (interpreted as characters) with a hex encoding.

Comment: `58d2f92539a5492fe6ef1e7375c6e9b6` is the hex encoded form of `XÒù%9¥I/æïsuÆé¶`. Note that in C++Builder 6, strings use an 8-bit ANSI encoding that is based on the user's locale, whereas Java strings use UTF-16 encoding. If you hash the raw bytes of the strings as-is, they are going to produce different results. If you want Java strings to hash the same way as C++Builder strings, you have to first convert Java strings to ANSI using `String.toBytes()` with a Charset that matches the C++ user's locale.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for Help.

So I try many codifications but any kind not equals result.
I receive data from database and get bytes from that.

```
result= u.getPass().getBytes();
```

After that I receive data from a form and calc hash.

```
m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
m.update(msg.getBytes(encoding),0,msg.length());
```

I send the codification using a parameter on my function.
When I go to builder program em try to get locale from that, return is just "C".

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you are converting a string to bytes and passing the bytes to MD5, but you are specifying the string length instead of the byte length. They are not the same thing. Save the bytes to a variable first, then pass the bytes and byte length to MD5